# which way is the correct way regarding sessions in php?

Tags: php, session

which way is the correct way regarding sessions in php?

Which way is the correct way, A or B? :

A:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
       session_start();
?>
        ...
```

Or

B:

```
<?php
       session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
        ...
```

Comment: `B)` is much better, put `session_start();` in the main file of Your site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B is always better

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
Note: To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before
outputing anything to the browser.
```

Answer (score 2):

Its B always the better option. And as far i have tried A wont even work.

You can even check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp they have also recomended the same.

Comment: True, because session_start() sends out bunch of headers...